# Parsing This Json with jsoncpp, c++

Tags: c++, json

Can someone please tell me how to parse this json data with the c++ library jsoncpp?

```
{
"data" : [
             [
                 "2017-02-14",
                 "A",
                 "mo",
                 111,
                 "OK"
             ],
             [
                 "2017-02-14",
                 "A",
                 "om",
                 111,
                 "OK"
             ],
             [
                 "2017-02-14",
                 "A",
                 "oft",
                 111,
                 "OK"
             ],
             [
                 "2017-02-14",
                 "A",
                 "ive",
                 111,
                 "OK"
             ]
         ]
}
```

This code does not work (str ends up being null)

```
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse(jsonData.c_str(), root);
string str = root["data"][0];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: you are right but i fixed it.  can you tell me how to parse it with the jsoncpp lib?

Comment: String should be enclosed in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **two layer bracket** in the string, so you should replace

```
string str = root["data"][0];
```

with

```
string str = root["data"][0][0].toStyledString();
```